# Offline Plotly: Generate bar chart of 2 columns on (y axis) & 1 column on ( x axis)

Tags: python, pandas, bar-chart, plotly-python

I like to generate offline bar chart of 3 columns (CLASS,POSITION,SCORE) from a big.tsv file for that I use Plotly.

I am looking for a code which can plot all classes with its respective values.

> For Example:  Class 1 have score 385.45 and 424.66 at position 5935161
>   and 5935162 respectively.

Here is the sample data:

```
    CLASS   POSITION    SCORE
1   5935162 385.45
1   5937168 424.66
2   5939544 1302.35
2   5948677 1501.93
3   153278829   1466.27
3   153284192   988.13
3   153284483   1432.21
4   153278829   1466.27
4   153284192   988.13
4   153284483   1432.21
5   153278829   1466.27
5   153284192   988.13
6   153284483   1432.21
6   153278829   1466.27
7   153284192   988.13
8   153284483   1432.21
8   153278829   1466.27
8   153284192   988.13
9   153284483   1432.21
10  153278829   1466.27
11  153284192   988.13
11  153284483   1432.21
12  153278829   1466.27
12  153284192   988.13
13  153284483   1432.21
A   153633359   617.39
A   153689893   1808.94
B   153880830   2507.65
B   153881525   2354.97
```

I  want to plot column 1 on X-axis and col 2& 3 on Y-axis but unable to write a code for it. But I successufully write a code with the help of tutorials which is  plotting col 1 & 3 but it is not printing all rows (G & F):

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
df = pd.read_csv('DATA.txt',"\t")
fig = px.bar(df, x = 'CLASS', y = 'SCORE')
fig.show()
```

The code generated following plot:
[Barchart doesn't represent the values of G & F][[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tFMUi.png)

It would be great if someone can help me to solve above query.

The suggested code generates following graph with incorrect order of x-axis [image: The order of bars is incorrect]

Comment: What version of plotly are you using?

Comment: As @ignoring_gravity said: since v4.0 plotly is offline only see [this](https://medium.com/plotly/plotly-py-4-0-is-here-offline-only-express-first-displayable-anywhere-fc444e5659ee). I suggest you to upgrade.

Comment: @ignoring_gravity '4.4.1'

Comment: `from plotly.offline` is old syntax from plotly 3 ... see rpanai's link for the new syntax, update your question, and then I'll help :)

Comment: Given that classes are repeated, which Position/Score value do you want to show for 1,2,3,G,F?

Comment: @ignoring_gravity updated. Kindly consider it.

Comment: @rpanai  Consider the attached graph which represents class 1,2,3 along with scores which lacks G, F rows I don't know why. The objective is that I want for each class there will be a bar which consists scores  along with positions. I also updated the  code a/c to the tutorial given by you. Thank you for that.

Comment: @rpanai  thankyou for the help just want to let you know that the given code works fine on sample data but when I apply it on actual data its not generating the bars in order (correct order:1,2,......9,A,B) while its generating (x-axis order: 1,10,11,12,13......9,A,B) I attached the image kindly consider it. Moreover, on hovering its only represent the value of first row (Example: when I hover class 1 it only shows score of first row 385.54).

Comment: Do you mind to share the data you're trying to plot?

Comment: @rpanai Thank you, for your reply. I attached the data. Kindly consider it

Comment: I see that, as example, Class 1 has two different Position and Score which one of the two do you want to plot? If you plot the two of them for that Class I guess the plot itself is not that easy to understand.

Comment: @rpanai Right Now, i just want to plot class on x-axis and score on y-axis

Comment: @adeha again you want 2 bars for classes 1 and 2, then 3 bars for classes 3 and 4 and so on?

Comment: @rpanai I want single bar for each class and the scores should be plot on y-axis just like the attached code  is doing. The issue is only unordered plotting of classes i.e. 1,10,11,12 and so on. While I want it to plot in order 1,2,3..13,A,B.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure about what do you want to achieve but having Position and Score on the same axis it doesn't sound like a great idea given that position can be more than 200.000x larger than score.

## Grouped bars

Here I take just one value for each class setting `df=df.groupby("CLASS").first().reset_index()`. The trick to show all the classes is to use `df.index` as x and then change `ticktext` on the layout.

```py
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objs as go

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=df.index,
                     y=df["POSITION"],
                     name="Position"))
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=df.index,
                     y=df["SCORE"],
                     name="Score"))

fig.update_layout(
    xaxis = dict(
        tickmode = 'array',
        tickvals = df.index,
        ticktext = df["CLASS"])
)
```

[image]

## Subplot

Here it's more or less the same but using two subplots.

```py
import pandas as pd
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.graph_objs as go

fig = make_subplots(rows=1, cols=2,
                    subplot_titles=["Position",
                                    "Score"]
                   )
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=df.index,
                     y=df["POSITION"],
                     name="Position"),
             row=1, col=1)
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=df.index,
                     y=df["SCORE"],
                     name="Score"),
             row=1, col=2)
fig['layout']['xaxis1'].update(dict(
        tickmode = 'array',
        tickvals = df.index,
        ticktext = df["CLASS"]))

fig['layout']['xaxis2'].update(dict(
        tickmode = 'array',
        tickvals = df.index,
        ticktext = df["CLASS"]))

fig.show()
```

[image]

## Update

Given the data you added recently you could try to use a placeholder to sort your `df` before plot.

```py
df = df.groupby("CLASS")["SCORE"].first().reset_index()

def fun(x):
    try:
        return str(int(x)).zfill(2)
    except:
        return x

df["ph"] = df["CLASS"].apply(fun)
df = df.sort_values("ph").reset_index(drop=True)


fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=df.index,
                     y=df["SCORE"],
                     name="Score"))

fig.update_layout(
    xaxis = dict(
        tickmode = 'array',
        tickvals = df.index,
        ticktext = df["CLASS"])
)
```

[image]